# Flutter check internet Connection using InternetAddress.lookup not working

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a class that is checking for network connection using [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) Package and then if there is a network connection it is checking if the internet is available using `InternetAddress.lookup`

the problem is that the connectivity Package is working ! and it is detected for Wi-Fi and mobile connection but the `InternetAddress.lookup` always returning `true` ! even of there is no internet !

Full Class Code :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class ConnectionStatusSingleton {
  static Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
        var res = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
        return res;
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        return false;
      }
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
        var res = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
        return res;
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

im calling it using :

```
 bool connectionState = await ConnectionStatusSingleton.checkConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use

```
Future<bool> isInternetConnected() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      var res = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        isInternet = res;
      });

      return res;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {

      setState(() {
        isInternet = false;
      });

      return false;
    }
  }
```

You don't seem to be doing anything specific based on wifi and cellular data so you can use this. Your problem seems to be the way you're handling the exception.

General understanding of the code is *"Try to connect to something on the internet, if the device has internet, it'll connect else it'll throw exception"*

In the above code I don't recommend using `setState()`. I've used it to satisfy an exact demand. You can tailor it accordingly.

Comment: did not work for me and it is still returning True ! ... the output is : `I/flutter ( 5113): [InternetAddress('172.217.20.14', IPv4)]` if ther is internet ... and if it is not : `[InternetAddress('142.250.185.174', IPv4)]` both of thiam is retuning true !

Comment: what i need is to chick there is internet connection not only if it is connected to Wi-Fi or network !

Comment: Try keeping the address to ```example.com```. The code is deployed in production and works fine for me. Also use a physical device to test, not an emulator.

Comment: still same after changing to example.com tested in real live Device (Samsung S10+) + in the Emulator > Full code :  Edited in the question

Comment: Any Solutions?, you have found. i am facing the same issue

Comment: I am trying to check device is connected with wifi but wifi has no internet connection.

Comment: @MohitJadav86 In that case you can try to ping a site and if that works then you can confirm that internet is there.

Comment: Yes, i have tryed with internetlookup and dart_ping plugin but still no success can you help on this?

 try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('amazon.com');
        var data = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
        debugPrint(
            " APIManagerUtils:: checkConnection >> wifi Internet Connected $data");
        return data;
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        debugPrint(
            " APIManagerUtils:: checkConnection >>wifi Internet Connected socket $e");
        return false;
      }